# What is correct objectClass for Domain Controller objects?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

While working on an application which queries AD for user information, I kept retrieving Domain Controllers as part of my results.

Using C# `DirectorySearcher` with the following filter:

```
"(objectClass=User)"
```

After some digging around, I noticed that for our DCs, the objectClass attribute is set to:

```
top; person; organizationalPerson; user; computer
```

It struck me kind of odd. However, I have no frame of reference and was not able to locate any specific documentation about it.

Can someone please advise if this looks right, if not, what should it be. Also, any documentation/best practices/standards regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you have to filter on 2 values.  First, `objectCategory=Computer` because domain controllers are a computer like any other, and second, you need to filter flags on the [userAccountControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute looking for servers with the [`ADS_UF_SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag.

[`ADS_UF_SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is 0x1000 or 8192 in decimal.  Doing a `binary and` on active-directory attributes is done using the [`1.2.840.113556.1.4.803`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269181) operator.  So, your query would ultimately look like this:

```
(&(objectCategory=computer)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=8192))
```

Comment: Tested and yes that only shows me DCs. Saved for future. However, my question was a bit broader. I was wondering if the "objectClass" is setup properly.

Comment: objectClass finds User accounts.  As strange as it sounds... even computers/domain-controllers have User accounts.  If you're looking for actual users, you should use organizationalPerson or something else... Machine accounts are used to communicate with each other in almost exactly the same manner as user accounts communicating with a user.  When a workstation joins the domain, a computer "user" account is created (usually named something similar to $computername ) and a unique password is created, and all secure transactions between servers is done using that account.

Answer (score 0):

Another query for domain controller objects that may perform better is (&(objectCategory=computer)(primaryGroupId=516)).  521 for Read-Only domain controllers.  Or for both: (&(objectCategory=computer)(|(primaryGroupId=516)(primaryGroupId=521)))

Probably not very noticeable in small domains, however in domains with large number of computer objects, the userAccountControl: queries may take a very long time.

If you are performing a query for the server object that appears in Active Directory Sites and Services, that would be: (objectCategory=server) and the base would need to be the configuration naming context.